# Stick element to bottom of viewport but don't cover page content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that to sticks to the bottom of the viewport and is wider than it's parent:

[image]

This is what I want. But the `button` also covers the content when the viewport is short which I don't want:

[image]

I'd like the `button` to stick to the bottom of the content when the viewport is smaller than the `button` plus the content as seen here when I remove `bottom:0` from `button`:

[image]

However then of course the `button` no longer sticks to the bottom of the viewport when the viewport is bigger than the content:

[image]

It is also important the button is the full width of the viewport- and it's parent's width smaller than the viewport. To accomplish this, I have the button positioned as absolute and the parent not positioned. Which is also why I can't seem to solve this with flex.

How can I accomplish this? Is it possible with just css or will I need to use javascript?

```css
body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .child {
        background: lightblue;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .parent {
        overflow: scroll;
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 30px;
      }
      button {
        border: 1px solid green;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        position: absolute; 
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />
        bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />
      </div>
      <button>button</button>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: you may let the child overflow instead ? https://jsfiddle.net/y54wkmtc/

Comment: Maybe add `padding-bottom` to the parent and make it have the same as the height of the button?

Comment: You want the button to stick to the bottom But not cover the content when the view is short, So `z-index:-1` should fix it ? Then the button will always stay behind content i'm feeling this is not what you want and therefore your question needs to be more specific

Comment: @ZohirSalak I was a bit more specific later in the question, I said I want it to stick to the bottom of the content when the view port is smaller. z-index would not accomplish that.

Comment: @EyalC something I was considering, but it would require javascript since this is for a reusable component that may have different sized buttons. So I was trying to see if theres a more css solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your problem, you might need JavaScript to properly evaluate/calculate the viewport height vs the child height, so you can stick the button to the bottom properly.

Consider the next solution:

```js
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
const child = document.querySelector('.child');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

function calculateHeight() {
  const childHeight = child && child.offsetHeight;
  // if the sum of child's height + button height is less than viewport, then make the button stick to the bottom
  button.classList.toggle('stick-to-bottom', (childHeight + button.offsetHeight) <= windowHeight);
}


// For demo only purposes, not relevant for the solution
let isOn = true;
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let content = 'bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />';
  if (isOn) {
     content = 'bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla';
  }
  
  child.innerHTML = content;
  isOn = !isOn;
  
  calculateHeight();
});
```

```css
body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .child {
        background: lightblue;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .parent {
        overflow: scroll;
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 30px;
      }
      button {
        border: 1px solid green;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
      }
      button.stick-to-bottom {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;        
      }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />
        bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />
      </div>
      <button>toggle content</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a few modifications to use the flex layout mode.

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.child {
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}

.parent {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br /> bla
    <br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />bla<br />
  </div>
  <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but as I said in the post the actual immediate parent has to be smaller than the button, not just the visible content.